# Alamofire requests slow?

Tags: json, swift, rest, alamofire

I have a function that makes multiple calls to a REST API.  The initial call is made, I get some values to make the next call and parse the JSON into custom objects.  Once I'm done I call the function again with a new URL.  I'm making a total of 8 calls and in total it takes around 10-14 seconds.  I'm using Alamofire for networking and SwiftyJSON to parse. I put in a bunch of time interval checks in the function to see what was taking up the greatest amount of time.  Once I get the JSON data back, running some logic and parsing takes a total of ~ 300ms but the time it takes when I make the request through Alamofire to getting the JSON back is 1.3 - 1.5 seconds.  I ran a ton of tests and the best I was able to get was 700ms for one call but most were over 1 second.  When I run them in Postman (a total of 8 with a 300ms delay) it takes 300ms to 700ms each.  Roughly twice as fast.  Does this sound right or should I be seeing requests take about as long as I do in Postman?  Using the same computer and running the app on a simulator and my phone with the same results.  Here is my stripped down code:

```
func parse() {
    Alamofire.request(jsonURL).responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let value):
            let json = JSON(value)
            //Check for 200 code
            if json["meta"]["code"].intValue == 200 {
                // doing lot of stuff
                }
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
            print("json failed")

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying to determine if the response comes back with 200 ok is usually slow from Alamofire. You could avoid the 200 and add some error handling that is run if there is an issue. It would be way faster. If you have any questions, please comment below.

Thanks,

Arnav Kaushik

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I removed that check and it doesn't seem to have had too much of an effect when I compare the time to postman.  I'll keep it out though just in case.

Comment: Can you post your logs and postman results please. Also, can you show me your code. If there isn't too much of an effect, you might want to keep the code in.